# Is there a way to suppress a prompt asking for query parameters when updating a data source (SAP) from an excel macro?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-bw

I am updating a data source from an Excel macro by running this:

```
Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "RefreshData", "DS_1")
```

That generates a prompt asking for the user to input query parameters. However, I just want to go with the already set parameters. Is there a way to suppress the prompt altogether or perhaps effectively just click OK when prompted? (perhaps finding the element that is the OK button and clicking it from the same macro, without resorting to absolute coordinates?)

The prompt that I want to suppress or obviate:

[image: The prompt that I want to suppress or obviate]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should pre-populate some of the fields and save the file. Some of the fields are mandatory, and maybe you have not filled them all out in the file you are loading and refreshing.

I am using `Call Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "RefreshData")` similarly, and I do not get a dialog box.

You could also try to set variables and then execute a refresh from within VBA using

```
Call Application.Run("SAPSetVariable", "my_variable", value, "INPUT_STRING", "DS_1") 
Call Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "RefreshData")
```